# Importing map from website into QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, embeddable-web-maps

I am trying to import the map on top of the page - into QGIS

https://www.licadho-cambodia.org/land_concessions/

I am reading the page source but not sure what is the URL I need.

I would like to import the map and the labels in the map.

Comment: There are different locations for different types of maps - the earth engine tiles loads into QGIS (xyz tiles) without issue. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I am trying to import the interactive map on the top, not the static ones on the bottom. I would like the date information the interactive map has. Thanks!

Comment: Go to the very bottom of the page there is a link to shapefile https://www.licadho-cambodia.org/land_concessions/ > 'https://www.licadho-cambodia.org/land_concessions/data/licadho-land-concessions-2020.zip'

Comment: Thank you so much, Mapperz! I got the map and the required label with it. Have a great day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Vector Data (in shapefile format) is available at the bottom of the page

```
https://www.licadho-cambodia.org/land_concessions/data/licadho-land-concessions-2020.zip
```

Here is an example of the data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this, Mapperz!!! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Then please accept the answer (click on the icon below the upvote/downvote triangle).